# Can we manipulate the TCP/IP protocols while browsing the internet?

Tags: tcp

As Internet is group of computers sharing a similar network with a set of TCP/IP protocols and such, can we in anyway program and change those protocols to manipulate the internet functionality?

Comment: Yes,you can change "the protocols". But nobody would understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality of the Internet depends on various devices such as routers to be working according to the same protocol. There isn't much use for a protocol, new or modified, that is not adopted for use by more than a few machines. Additionally, specific parameters of protocols can often be configured, but depending on the setting, they can potentially break the network if misconfigured. Some of them can be configured as operating system options in your PC. Many browser options for HTTP can affect the functionality of browsing the web enough to be noticeable. For example, changing the user agent string (not recommended for normal use) will show the web page as it's meant to be displayed on another platform.